# Evaluate $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin \frac{k \pi}{n}$ where $\text{gcd}(n,k)=1$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Prove that $\prod\limits_{1 \le k \le n-1,gcd(n,k)=1} \sin \frac{k \pi}{n}=\frac{1}{2^{\phi (n)}}$ where $n$ is not a power of a prime number.

**My attempt**:

$S=\prod\limits_{1 \le k \le n-1,gcd(n,k)=1} \sin \frac{k \pi}{n}=(2i)^{-\phi (n)}*\prod\limits_{1 \le k \le n-1,gcd(n,k)=1}(e^{\frac{ik \pi}{n}}-e^{\frac{-ik \pi}{n}})=(2i)^{-\phi (n)}*e^{-\sum\limits_{1 \le k \le n-1,gcd(n,k)=1} \frac{k \pi}{n}}*\prod\limits_{1 \le k \le n-1,gcd(n,k)=1} (e^{\frac{2ik \pi}{n}}-1)$

No we use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456273/sum-of-all-positive-integers-less-than-n-and-relatively-prime-to-n)lemma and we have:

$S=(2i)^{- \phi (n)}*(-i)^{\phi(n)}*\prod\limits_{1 \le k \le n-1,gcd(n,k)=1} (e^{\frac{2ik \pi}{n}}-1)=(-2)^{- \phi (n)}*\prod\limits_{1 \le k \le n-1,gcd(n,k)=1} (e^{\frac{2ik \pi}{n}}-1)=2^{- \phi (n)}*\prod\limits_{1 \le k \le n-1,gcd(n,k)=1}(1-e^{\frac{2ik \pi}{n}})$

So it only remains to prove $\prod\limits_{1 \le k \le n-1,gcd(n,k)=1}(1-e^{\frac{2ik \pi}{n}})=1$.Which I can't do.My attempt was based on [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1)problem but the rest can't be continued with that method.And also I don't know how to use $n$ not being power of a prime.

Comment: Plz change the title if it looks inappropriate.

Comment: *Only a note:* A question about $\prod\limits_{1 \le k \le n-1,gcd(n,k)=1}(x-e^{\frac{2ik \pi}{n}})$ may fit better to https://mathoverflow.net/ where some experts are answering .

Comment: @user90369 Really not I am a high school student who is studying for IMO and I got this from one of the books I am studying so indeed it is not appropriate for math overflow.

Comment: Then something of that you have studied should give an idea how to solve it. I hope you'll find the answer in you books, because it's (at least for me) an interesting question. :-)

Comment: @user90369 It is not solved in that book so I will add a bounty to get a result.

Comment: Once you know the name, results are easy to find: You are trying to evaluate a [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) at 1. The question has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49956/value-of-cyclotomic-polynomial-evaluated-at-1

Comment: @Long How should we prove $x^n-1 = \Pi_{d|n}\Phi_d(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered here: [Value of cyclotomic polynomial evaluated at 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49956/value-of-cyclotomic-polynomial-evaluated-at-1)

I'll provide a proof for $x^n-1 = \prod_{d|n} \Phi_d(x)$:

$x^n -1$ has $n$ distinct roots $1,a=e^{2\pi i/n},a^2,...,a^{n-1}$, so we can write $x^n-1 = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x-a^k)$.

Next we can partition the numbers $0,..,n-1$ by the greatest common divisor with $n$:

$$\prod_{d|n} \prod_{0\leq k \leq n-1 \\ \gcd(k,n)=d} (x-a^k)
=\prod_{d|n} \prod_{0\leq k \leq n-1 \\ \gcd(k,n)=d} (x-(a^d)^{k/d})
=\prod_{d|n} \prod_{0\leq l \leq n/d-1 \\ \gcd(l,n)=1} (x-(a^d)^l)
$$

Note that $a^d$ generates the $n/d$-th roots of unity, so
$$\prod_{d|n} \prod_{0\leq l \leq n/d-1 \\ \gcd(l,n)=1} (x-(a^d)^l)
= \prod_{d|n} \Phi_{n/d}(x)
= \prod_{d|n} \Phi_d(x)$$